# sqlsrv array doesn't return all rows

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I can't seem to figure out why `sqlsrv_fetch_assoc` only returns 1 row when there are 2 rows in the result set according to `sqlsrv_num_rows`. I've tried to hard code the parameter, but I still get the same result.

**SSMS Result Set**

```
id     description
------ -------------
2      Administrator
3      User
```

**PHP**

```
$col = 'abcd';
$stmt = "SELECT id, [description] FROM dbo.tbl WHERE col = ?";
$params = array( $col );
$options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );

$query = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $stmt, $params, $options );
if( $query === false ) {
    print( print_r( sqlsrv_errors() ) );
}

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC )) {
    ...
}
```

When I try to view the result set

```
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC );

print_r($row);
```

I receive

```
Array
(
    [id] => 2
    [description] => Administrator
)
```

**sqlsrv_num_rows**

```
echo sqlsrv_num_rows( $query );
//Returns 2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> When I try to view the result set
>
> $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC );
>            print_r($row);`

Since you listed this separately, I hope you're not doing this (showing all code):

```
$col = 'abcd';
$stmt = "SELECT id, [description] FROM dbo.tbl WHERE col = ?";
$params = array( $col );
$options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );

$query = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $stmt, $params, $options );
if( $query === false ) {
    print( print_r( sqlsrv_errors() ) );
}

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC )) {
    ...
    $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC );
    print_r($row);
}
```

Because then it's obvious you're consuming sqlsrv_fetch_array **twice** per loop iteration, once for the condition check and once *inside* the loop.

Remove all fluff from the while loop and have just this - and absolutely nothing else, not even the ... or comments.

```
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC )) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: Yep. There was another `$stmt / $query` inside the `while` loop. This wrote over the previous result set and ended the loop. Figured it out then tried to delete my question. Have 25 rep.

Comment: Well, I'm glad you didn't :)  Because now I'm benefiting.

Answer (score 3):

> [`sqlsrv_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php): Returns the **next** available row of data as an associative array, a numeric array, or both (the default).

Emphasis by me.

> Return Values: Returns an array on success, NULL if there are no more rows to return, and FALSE if an error occurs.

You'll need to do a while loop to fetch all records, like this:

```
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC )) {
    //process $row
}
```

Comment: Should have mentioned that this is already inside a `while` loop.

Comment: does this do 1 query for each row then?

Comment: Nope, 1 query altogether, and *rownum* fetch calls.

Answer (score 0):

I'm under the impression that `fetch_array` only retrieves a row at a time (a row being the NEXT row)... Try something like...

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC );){ 

//do something awesome 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to use sqlsrv_fetch_array and use multi dimensional array to store each row data. But on doing so make sure to use $i++ instead of $i += 1 
If we use $i +=1 then only single row is saved.

```
   $i = 0;
   while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC )) {
        $result[$i][0] = $row['id'];
        $result[$i][1] = $row['description'];

        $i++;    //works 
       // $i += 1; //does not work with this !
    }
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code serve me finally Thanks to "Ashish". I don't understand why its not upvoted.

```
$Result = array();
$sql  = "EXEC CRM_TestSP;";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

$i = 0;
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    $Result[$i]["Description"] = $row['Description'];
    $i++;
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
return $Result;
```

It returns an array like this:

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["Description"]=> string(4) "Text 1" } [1]=> array(1) { ["Description"]=> string(4) "Text2" } } 1
```

That's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56363304/7208109

Comment: All regards for Ashish.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql  = "SELECT id, description FROM dbo.tbl";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}
$data = array();
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    $data[] = array(
                "description" => $row['description']
                );  
}

return $data;
```

Comment: Hy, welcome to [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/). Please add some description to define your code also see [How to write a good anser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).